Installed zed via script but can't launch it via `zed .`
I installed zed via the installation script curl -f https://zed.dev/install.sh | sh .
I am trying to launch it from the commandline in the project directory I am working in using
zed .

but getting the error
zsh: command not found: zed

I tried searching for the binary using where zed and which zed but both can't seem to locate zed zed not found
The funny thing is that I can access zed via the applications menu


did you test zeditor? I'm using zeditor . on my Manjaro and it open the editor.

You will need to figure out where Zed installed its CLI binary. On my macOS system it's /usr/local/bin/zed, and the path is visible in the Zed UI via a popup message when you run the "Install CLI" command:

Installed 'zed to /usr/local/bin/zed. You can launch Zed from your terminal.

Then you need to make sure your shell's PATH has that directory in it. You can examine the value with echo $PATH and edit your shell startup files (probably .bashrc or .zshrc in your home directory) if you need to change it.
